Initializing Radar in NextJs using and inline script in the layout is not working
I am using Radar (radar.com) to do some work with location data and maps. To run any of the code I need to initialize Radar with my personal key. I am trying to run this code in the root layout file so that it only gets run once, but I can't get the NextJs Script tag to work.
Here is my code in the root layout file.
<Script strategy="afterInteractive" id="radar">
          {`Radar.initialize("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")`}
        </Script>

The problem is when I load the page it says that "Radar is not defined" even though I have the correct page being imported to the layout file.
I have tried to initialize the code any time I call anything from the Radar SDK, but that seems to be causing there to be too many instances of Radar initialized on the page.
